# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning `JPA` and `Hibernate` from Udemy. I might be making a silly mistake. None of the answers helped me so far.

This is my project structure:

[image]

Here's my code:

**Main.java**

```
package client;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import entity.Guide;  // <--- an entity
import entity.Student;  // <--- another entity
...
public class CascadesClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Transaction txn = session.getTransaction();
                try {
                    txn.begin();
                    
                    //persisting a new Student (using CascadeType.PERSIST) along with its associated Guide
                    Guide guide = new Guide("2000IM10901", "Ian Lamb", 2000);
                    Student student = new Student("2014AL50456", "Amy Gill", guide);
                    session.persist(student);       
                    txn.commit();
                }   catch(Exception e) {
                        if(txn != null) { txn.rollback(); }
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }   finally {
                        if(session != null) { session.close(); }
                }
    
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
package entity;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Student {
  ...
}
```

**Guide.java**

```
package entity;    
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Guide {
  ...
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tbdone</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">cosmonauts</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        
        <!-- Pretty print the SQL in the log file and console -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        
        <!-- Create/update tables automatically using mapping metadata -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        
        <mapping class="entity.Guide" />    
        <mapping class="entity.Student" />
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**pom dependencies**

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Why I'm getting this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: entity.Student    at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:752)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:735)
> at client.CascadesClient.main(CascadesClient.java:23)

Comment: You should tell somehow Hibernate what are you Entity classes so that Hibernate can scan them for mapping metadata. Maybe that's the problem. Try to read this here about bootstraping https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that dialect was the issue.

Below changes in *hibernate.cfg.xml* solved my issue:

```
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try to add the following to your xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>entity</value> 
    </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

  
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```